# Google analytics ADD-ON google spreadsheets : AVG Session duration and Pagesviews/sessions

Tags: analytics, spreadsheet, google-analytics-api, dashboard

Im working on a custom google spreadsheet analytics dashboard.

Here's the situation, I'm trying to get specific info:
Sessions, users, pageviews pageviews/sessions, avg session duration, bouncerate and % new sessions.

The thing is I almost have all the right information except for AVG Session duration and Pageviews/sessions.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
http://puu.sh/i2rGf/37b2dab3fb.png (its the yellow and the pink one)

Google returns the value's in seconds where you easily devide by 86400
well, I've tried that and no result.

Its kinda weird because everyone is talking about a result like 1234.1234
but mine is 1234.1234.1234.1234 ?

Ideas on where the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the locale in your spreadsheet settings. It needs to be US to match the GA data being sent.

Comment: Thanks, fixed my problem.
I formatted the cells to time duration and devided by 86400 and it worked.